# List size validation in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, validation, size

is it possible to check if there is any item in a list?

Comment: When you say List do you mean the Flex List class?  Or an Array?  Or one of the Collection classes (Such an ArrayCollection or XMLListCollection)?

Comment: spark list class, thank you all for the answers

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, Be sure to mark it as such.  If not please expand on why it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

It is better that you check the underlying bound data structure than the mx.controls.List (assuming that's what you mean by 'list') class, which should be handling your display logic only.

I'll assume that you have a list setup bound to an ArrayCollection.  You can then just check the array collection length.  This is the way you should do it, keep your logic out of the UI view.

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var data:ArrayCollection

            public function isDataInList():Boolean {
                 return (data != null && data.length > 0)
            }
       ]]>
</fx:Script>


<mx:List id="source" dataProvider="{data}"/>
```

Comment: +1 for the code.  I'm unclear if the @Jack wanted a List class or was using list as a generic term for 'dataProvider'.  That said, in the mx List class the dataProvider is a generic object; so you can't guarantee the dataProvider has a length property.  I expect most dataProviders will, but you'll probably get a compiler error if you don't cast 'data' in your code sample.  The spark List dataProvider on the other hand must implement the IList interface; which does have a length property.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by list.

If you mean a class that implements the [IList interface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/IList.html), then you can find out by checking the length property:

```
public function hasData(iListInstance:IList):Boolean{
 if(iListInstance.length > 0){
   return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

If you mean an instance of the [MX List class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/List.html) or [Spark List class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html), you should access the dataProvider of that class, not class itself, to find out if it has items in it.  For a spark List you might do something like this:

```
public function hasData(list:List):Boolean{
 if((list.dataProvider) && (list.dataProvider.length > 0)){
   return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

The Spark list requires a dataProvider that implements the IList; so you can access the length property directly.  If you're using a mx list; then you'll have to cast the dataProvider to it's type:

```
public function hasData(list:List):Boolean{
 if((list.dataProvider) && (list.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).length > 0)){
   return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

If you are using the term 'list' to refer, generically, to something any collection of data, such as an Array, or an XMLList, or something else you'll have to look at specifics of that data type to figure out how to decide if the data type is empty (or not).

Answer (score 1):

Use `numElements` for `spark` and `numChildren` for `halo (mx)`

```
if (list.numElements == 0) {
 // no elements in a list
}
```